# The young lady, a young man - why different articles?

Tags: articles

I came across two examples on [YourDictionary.com](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/quite) and would like to know why these sentences use ***different articles?***

> You're growing into quite **the** young lady.
>   He was getting to be quite **a** handsome young man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article choice here is really random & influenced mostly by habit.

Swap the articles in the sentences and you yield the same meanings and raise no native-speaker eyebrows.

That said, the "quite the young lady" usage does have a slightly more formal, old-fashioned connotation (think Jackie O's white gloves & pillbox hats).

I'd advise to stick with "a".

Answer (score 0):

What G. Ann is said is essentially right: that the two constructions are basically interchangeable. However, in some cases they may have slightly different meanings. In particular:

> You are growing into quite a young lady.

This would be understood as referencing the quality of the individual's character or achievements, just like "quite the young lady."

> You are quite the young lady.

will only ever be understood in the same manner as the previous sentence.

However, consider this sentence:

> You are quite a young lady.

While it could be interpreted the same way, it could also mean that the subject is particularly young.

The problem seems to be an *open compound noun* used as a subject: that is, a set of unhyphenated words that form a noun not given by the sum of its component words. If the first word in the compound is an adjective, it produces ambiguity.  This is quite a rare situation, but in such a case, using *the* probably will make the meaning clear.